# How to set shipping only for one country and it's division or district?

Tags: magento, country

I want to know that, how to set shipping for a country and it's division or district.

For example:

My country is Bangladesh and it's division's are
Dhaka
Chittagong
Comilla

And I want to set different shipping cost for different divisions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  need to make 3 different Rules for  3 cases in Magento administrators panel under Sales->Tax->Manage Tax Zone Rates. then You  need to mention all the 3 in Sales->Tax->Manage Tax Rules .